# C# & VueJS - split list based on an enum value rather than order

Tags: c#, vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of Options on my Model that is passed into my template.

Each tile returns a collection of options, which all have an enum associated to them

```
public class Tile {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
   ...
   public OptionTypes OptionType { get; set; } = OptionTypes.Simple;
}
```

Now, in my template, I am struggling to split the values between two option menus - Essentially, I want to split the list based on the value of the enum but I've had no luck.

I can't see a way to chunk it that's not in a particular order and tried to use v-if to check the enum value

```
<li v-for="option in parentData.options" v-if="option.optionType #####">
      <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
</li>
```

that didn't work either.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks! I'm fairly new to Vue and the rest of the code has been snipped a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put the equal sign in the v-if.

```
<li v-for="option in parentData.options" v-if="option.optionType === #####">
      <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
</li>
```

Also make sure the data is in json format.

Comment: Sorry, I had just removed that, I actually had tried v-if="option.optionType === 'optiontypes.simple" and so on, but didn't know how to call the enum?

Comment: I didn't even realise the enum index value was stored against option.optionType, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The enum index was already assigned to option.optionType so I just needed to check against that - Not exactly the solution I want in case the enum changed but for my purposes it's fine.